# What does this domain notation "\" mean?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have to compute an integral with the domain $D$. I don't know what the "\" means. Here is the domain description.
D = {(x, y) : x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup> $\leq 4$} \ {(x, y) : (x - 1)<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup> $\leq 1$}

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $A\setminus B$ is the [set difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Relative_complement), $\{x\in A\mid x\not\in B\}$

Comment: The notation "$\setminus $" has quite a lot of different meanings. Think of the orbit space $\Gamma \backslash X$. In your example it is of course the set difference.

Comment: Is an operator that applies to sets and in result it excludes from first set all elements common with the second set.

Answer (score 2):

It means 'but not' So it would refer do the region being a circle centered at the origin but excluding the region (x-1)^2 + y^2 <= 1

Answer (score 1):

$D_1 := \{(x,y) ~:~x^2+y^2\le4\}$ is the interior of a disk centered at the origin with radius $2$.

$D_2 := \{(x,y) ~:~(x-1)^2+y^2\le1\}$ is the interior of a disk centered at $(1,0)$ with radius $1$. $D_2$ lies entirely inside $D_1$ except for a single intersection at $(2,0)$.

In this context, $\setminus$ denotes the [set difference](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SetDifference.html) operation, so $D=D_1 \setminus D_2$ is the set of points belonging to the first disk, but not to the second disk. This is the crescent-shaped region shown in [Wolfram|Alpha's](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%5E2%2By%5E2%3C%3D4+and+not+%28x-1%29%5E2%2By%5E2%3C%3D1) "inequality plot".

[image]